# Lights moving fast and in a straight line coming from the northwest headed southeast tonight at 9:15CST

Tags: star, earth, rotation, artificial-satellite

What is going on tonight?
Bright lights in the same high orbit moving very fast across the night sky from Northwest heading southeast...then 10 minutes later same line but far fewer almost in identical location....this was at 9:15 CST tonight 4/26/20